# Can we deduce that $0\in \operatorname{int}(X-Y)$?

Tags: general-topology

Suppose that $X$ and $Y$ are two subsets of a Hilbert space.

Is it true that $(\operatorname{int}X)\cap Y\neq \emptyset$

implies that $0\in \operatorname{int}(X-Y)$?

Comment: Your notation is ambiguous.  By $\text{int}\, X \cap Y$, do you mean $\text{int}(X \cap Y)$ or $\text{int}(X) \cap Y$?

Comment: The question in the title seems to be distinctly different from that in the body of the question.

Comment: what if $X=Y$, what does Hilbert space have to do with this (apart from $0$ being defined)? What does $X−Y$ mean, is it set difference (in which case the question is way too easy with answer no), or perhaps it means Minkowski difference as in en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minkowski_addition, i.e. $X-Y=\{x-y:x\in X, y\in Y\}$? P.S. I just saw you clarify in a comment to an answer that you mean Minkowski difference, please edit your question so that it would be clear what you mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Subject to your clarification that $X-Y=\{x-y:x\in X, y\in Y\}$ denotes Minkowski difference.

Say $y\in(\operatorname{int}X)\cap Y$. Then $0\in (\operatorname{int}X)-y$ and the latter set is open and contained in $X-Y$, hence $0\in(\operatorname{int}X)-y\subseteq\operatorname{int}(X-Y)$.

Answer (score 1):

**For the question in the title:** No -- for a counterexample take $X=\mathbb R$ and $Y=\mathbb Q$.

**For the question in the question body:** No -- for a counterexample, let $X$ and $Y$ both be the entire Hilbert space.

Comment: For the question in the question body: I do not see this a counterexample.

Comment: @user35616: What confuses you about it? If $X$ and $Y$ are both the entire Hilbert space, then $\operatorname{int}(X)\cap Y$ is _also_ the entire Hilbert space, which is different from $\emptyset$. But $X\setminus Y$ is the empty set, whose interior is empty and therefore _does not_ contain $0$.

Comment: By $X-Y$ I mean the Minkowski difference which is the entire Hilbert space.

Comment: @user35616: It would behoove you to define such things in your question instead of relying on telepathy ...